# Send new data for each HTTP Request in Apache JMeter

Tags: apache, http, scripting, jmeter, httprequest

I have a HTTP sampler containing body data:

```
{
"voice": "Nancy",
"basic": "sad",
"type": "basic",
"text": "She fell."
}
```

I set the number of threads to 50 and ramp up period to 10 seconds.
I have a set of sentences that need to be filled in the "text" field.

```
She had your dark suit in greasy washwater all year.
Don't ask me to carry an oily rag like that.
This was easy for me.
Jane may earn more money by working hard.
She is thinner than I am.
Bright sunshine shimmers on the ocean.
......... another 42 sentences
```

> total:50 (one for each request)

That is when a new request is fired, I need a new sentence to be in the "text" field.

How to handle this case is it using BeanShell script or uuid??

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Once Only Controller" to your test plan with the below samplers to initialize the file read

--> Beanshell Sampler 1

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; 
//String sCWd = new String(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir().replace("\\\\", "/"));
String sCWd = new String(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir());
log.info("CWDString=" + sCWd.replace("\\", "/"));

vars.put("CWD", sCWd.replace("\\\\", "/"));
log.info("CWD=" + vars.get("CWD"));
```

--> Beanshell Sampler 2

```
${__CSVRead(${CWD}/<<yourfilename.csv>>,*hMyText)}
${__CSVRead(*hMyText,next)}
```

Then under your main HTTP request sampler, add a beanshell preprocessor

HTTP sampler

--> Beanshell preprocessor

```
vars.put("mynewtext", "${__CSVRead(*hMyText,0)}");
```

Then substitute your request body in the http sampler as

```
{
"voice": "Nancy",
"basic": "sad",
"type": "basic",
"text": "${mynewtext}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any scripting, just go for [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function like:

```
{
  "voice": "Nancy",
  "basic": "sad",
  "type": "basic",
  "text": "${__StringFromFile(/path/to/file/with/text.txt,,,)}"
}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on this and other JMeter Functions.

If your file has > 1 column it may be more feasible to use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Comment: I tried this function and it works but it picks out strings randomly but not in a specific order. Any help how to get the strings in order?

Comment: It picks next string from the file each time it's being called, the values should not be random.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way could be using Config Element->"CSV Data Set Config".
Put all 50 sentences in a text file in any path like D:/myfile.txt
Now in CSV Data Set Config, set filename ie complete location, define variable name as "myvalue" and pass parameter as ${myvalue} in request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue in many ways, below are the two ways
  1. using "__RandomString()"
  2. Using BeanShell program
  3. Using "Random Variable" and Epoch time (Config Element -> Random Variable)

Recommended options are 1 and 3

1. "using "__RandomString()": Below is the code snippet

   ```
   {
     "voice": "Nancy",
     "basic": "sad",
     "type": "basic",
   "text":"${__RandomString(32,abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyz,0123456789)}",
   ```

   }

2 . Using BeanShell program: Below is the code snippet using beanshell Preprocessor

```
Step 1: Add "Beanshell preprocessor" to "Http" sampler as child

import java.util.Random;
  String str="abcdefghijklmnopqrst1234567890";
  int String_Length=32;
  String randomSting="";
  for(int i=1;i<=String_Length;i++){
   Random randomVal=new Random();
   int randomInt=randomVal.nextInt(str.length());
   randomSting+=str.substring(randomInt, randomInt+1);
   }     
vars.put("random_variable",randomSting);
```

Step 2: Call random_variable (as defined in beanshell preprocessor) in "Http Sampler" , as shown below

```
{
  "voice": "Nancy",
  "basic": "sad",
  "type": "basic",
  "text":"${random_variable}"
  }
```

3. Add "Random Variable " to "http sampler" as a child and call ramdom variable name(is UUID ) in http sampler 
   [image]

> ```
> {
>   "voice": "Nancy",
>   "basic": "sad",
>   "type": "basic",
>    "text":"perf text ${__javaScript((new Date().getTime()))}_${UUID}@c1.dev"
> }
> ```

For source , please click here [enter link description here](https://github.com/mcheepati/JmeterScripts/blob/master/Dynamic_Text_creations.jmx)